# iOS CSS native scroll feeling

Tags: css, web, scroll

When scrolling in the following website: http://bootstrap-themes.github.io/marketing/ with my iOS device I get a native scrolling feeling. How do I implement this in my CSS?

I've tried adding the following code in my body tag in CSS without success

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Kind regards,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by native scrolling feeling?  Website scrolling should default to the browser.

Comment: If you try to scroll the page I linked, you can see that the scrolling doesn't stop immediately, it keeps scrolling for another 1-2 seconds, and it's scrolling very smooth (this is the native feeling. I feel like I'm scrolling in iOS settings).

Then try to scroll on e.g. stackoverflow, and you'll see that you don't have the same scroll feeling.